# Unable to boot the Simulator. Xcode version 14.3

Tags: macos, ios-simulator

[image]

Regularly, I'm using this simulator, but now I suddenly see this error. Can you tell me how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

**Now I have found the answer to this question.**

**Problem:**

This is an Xcode cache error.

**Doing:**

I removed the catch.

**Steps:**

*step 1:*

go to setting -> search to -> storage

[image]

*step 2:*

Search Storage

[image]

*step 3:*

[image]

*step 3:*

**If you see the cache, then clear that cache.**

*step 4:*

[image]

I was working seamlessly.